# If $K \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is compact then $x+K$ and $\lambda K$ are compact too, where $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}, \lambda\in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

Prove that if $K$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ then for each $x\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and each $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ the subsets
\begin{split}
x+K & := \{ x+k \mid  k \in K\} \\
\lambda k & := \{\lambda k \mid k \in K \}
\end{split}

are compact.

Do u have any ideas for this?
Should I prove that the subsets are closed and bounded?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Continuous functions map compact sets into compact sets.

Comment: So we can see $y+K$ like the image of  $f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}^{n}$ where $f(x): x +y$ with $y \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, and because $f(x)$ is continuous then $x+K$ is compact. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fact that a set $M\subset \mathbb{R^n}$ is compact if and only if every sequence $x_n\in M$ has a convergent subsequence in $M$. Since every sequence $y_n$ in $x+K$ or $\lambda K$ is of the form $y_n=x+x_n$ or $y_n=\lambda x_n$ with $x_n \in K$, you can use the compactness of $K$ to show that $y_n$ does in fact have a convergent subsequence which converges in $x+K$ or $\lambda K$.

On the other hand, it is easy to see that $x+K$ and $\lambda K$ are bounded if and only if $K$ is bounded. We then just have to show that every convergent sequence in $x+K$/$\lambda K$ also has a limit in $x+K$/$\lambda K$. Here we can again just use the fact that every sequence $y_n$ in $x+K$/$\lambda K$ can be written as $y_n = x + x_n$/$\lambda x_n$ with $x_n \in K$.

Answer (score 0):

One approach you can take is to prove that the translation by $x$ and the dilation by $\lambda$, i.e. the mappings,
$$
f(y) = x + y, \; g(y) = \lambda y,
$$
are both continuous mappings (and, optionally, are even [homeomorphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism)) from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to itself.  Continuous maps preserve compactness.